# Integrate MS Teams video calls on my web application

Tags: outlook, microsoft-teams, video-embedding

I am building an angular project where I am looking to integrating MS Teams/Outlook video calls.

Basically, if we have an invitation link for a call, can that be opened into my own external app? Or, somehow can we embed MS Teams calling interface on my app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using [Azure Communication Services Web (JS) SDK](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/tree/main/add-1-on-1-video-calling). Could you please take a look at [Teams interop on Azure Communication Services documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-with-video-calling?pivots=platform-web).

Comment: Can this solution be applied for calls with more than 2 participants, i.e meeting calls instead of one-to-one?

Comment: Yes, here is sample for meeting chat: https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/app-acs-calling